# Python Text Cleaning Remove spaces between non alpha numeric characters

Tags: python, parsing, text

I have a text-file with alphanumeric and non-alphanumeric characters in the text.

I want to remove any spaces that are between two non-alphanumeric characters.

How can I achieve this efficiently?

Any method/popular libraries is fine.

Comment: *from re import sub* should give you a start.

Comment: regex is quite useful for this purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a possible solution to your question:

```
import re

file = """
    7     u         p, S   a k    s F i f t h A v e, A u d i A     4, C a n o n A 7 5
"""

print re.sub(r"([A-Za-z0-9])\ *([A-Za-z0-9])\ *", r"\1\2", file)
```

I think [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) is a good way to go here.

Comment: `x   y           ##` will result in `xy##`. Anyway, it's not a good idea to encourage questions that show neither research nor effort by spoon feeding them a solution.

Comment: @spectras That's true, this solution won't work for your counterexample, nice catch. On the other hand, I don't agree with your point of view of not encouraging these type of low quality questions, why not? why not being proactive and trying to create good answers?

Comment: Admittedly, that's my own personal opinion on a [recurring](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255657/answering-questions-that-show-lack-of-research/255660) controversial [point](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255459/is-it-okay-to-downvote-answers-to-bad-questions) on SO. I don't personally downvote because of that, but I do mention it in a comment every now and then, when question shows especially low effort and answer is very unlikely to be useful to other people. Anyway, either linked meta question is a better place than here to discuss this :)

Comment: @spectras Fair enough, in any case your downvote makes sense because the code isn't solving properly the question as you've proved with your counterexample ;)

Comment: @user113531> the point being, if you just copy-paste the title of your question in google, you instantly get `re.sub` as first answer (well, second now). Right in the google preview, without even having to actually open the link. Worth trying before posting the question on SO.